# How to get timezone detail by zip code, from Geocoding and Search API v7 of here-mep?

Tags: here-api

I was trying to fetch the city, state, county, lat, lng and timezone details of a particular zip by calling `https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1//geocode` with parameters `in=countryCode:USA&qq=postalCode=75080&apiKey=myapikey` the result i got is

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "75080, TX, United States",
            "id": "here:cm:namedplace:22182383",
            "resultType": "locality",
            "localityType": "postalCode",
            "address": {
                "label": "75080, TX, United States",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "countryName": "United States",
                "state": "Texas",
                "postalCode": "75080"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 32.94534,
                "lng": -96.76162
            },
            "mapView": {
                "west": -96.7075,
                "south": 32.93728,
                "east": -96.76902,
                "north": 33.0038
            },
            "scoring": {
                "queryScore": 1.0,
                "fieldScore": {
                    "postalCode": 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to fetch the timezone details by calling the old api`https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json` with parameters `locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone` is there a way to get the same in new api also ? or what should i do to get the timezone details ?

Answer (score 0):

you can still use the older API as it is in maintenance phase but not completely blocked.

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone&apiKey={}E&countyCode=USA&postalcode=75080
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-geocode.html

Comment: so no way to get this in new api ?